# Potentially suffering from over optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, animation, optimization

I have this design for the front page of a personal website I'm making:

[image: initial state]

[image: final state]

You click on the respective icon and it expands to reveal info.I went through two other designs that didn't work out, but incorporated similar animations. After modifying the JS after each iteration I realized that I was:

1. Encountering bits of redundant code
2. Starting to consider the potentiality of adding more tabs/sections in the future (that I might need to make the code scale)

This lead me to start **'generacizing'** my code. So making functions like 'handleHorizontalTabs' or 'handleVerticalTabs' rather than 'handleGamesTab' or 'handlePhotographyTab' This would avoid me writing a whole new function for the photography tab, which differs from the games tab by only one css property. So I was thinking, **well then I'm going to need to pass in an object rather than an exact ID**. Then I created some object literals that stored all of their respective properties. The problem with creating neutral animation functions like this (in my case at least) is that I **HAVE** to define every property that could be used in the function **even if it's not used.** Consider this snippet before you scroll to the full code:

```js
if (active){
    // Only animate horizontally
    $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({
        width: elemToAnimate.ExpandedWidth,
        left: elemToAnimate.ExpandedLeft,
       right: elemToAnimate.ExpandedRight
    }, animateDuration)
}
```

I might not need to change the say,**'left'** property, when animating. But because this is a general function it doesn't know that. So, in my object literal I still have to define it (it would just be the original value). I did notice (and I left the game section unchanged so you could see this) that if I simply leave it out of the literal, it is marked as `undefined` and has no effect on the animation. I could do this, but I don't think that's good practice. Plus anyone reading my code would be asking where that property is.

My question is two fold:

1. What should I consider programmatically when taking the **scalability** of an app into account?
2. How can this code be cleaned up/refined?

The code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rc6wnsst/
(PS Not browser optimized; use Mozilla if you can)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Definitions 
//Define object literals
var aboutmeSection = {id: '#aboutme-section', get ID() {return this.id;},
                      selector: '#person-icon', get Selector() {return this.selector;},
                      origWidth: $('#aboutme-section').css('width'), get OrigWidth() {return this.origWidth;},
                      origLeft: $('#aboutme-section').css('left'), get OrigLeft() {return this.origLeft;},
                      origRight: 'auto', get OrigRight() {return this.origRight;},
                      origHeight: $('#aboutme-section').css('height'), get OrigHeight() {return this.origHeight;},
                      origTop: $('#aboutme-section').css('top'), get OrigTop() {return this.origTop;},
                      origBottom: $('#aboutme-section').css('bottom'), get OrigBottom() {return this.origBottom;},
                      expandedWidth: '65%', get ExpandedWidth() {return this.expandedWidth;},
                      expandedLeft: $('#aboutme-section').css('left'), get ExpandedLeft() {return this.expandedLef;},
                      expandedRight: $('#aboutme-section').css('right'), get ExpandedRight() {return this.expandedRight;},
                      expandedHeight: '450px', get ExpandedHeight() {return this.expandedHeight;},
                      expandedTop: '65%', get ExpandedTop() {return this.expandedTop;},
                      expandedBottom: $('#aboutme-section').css('bottom'), get ExpandedBottom() {return this.expandedBottom;}};

var photographySection = {id: '#photography-tab', get ID() {return this.id;},
                           selector: '#camera-icon', get Selector() {return this.selector;},
                           origWidth: $('#photography-tab').css('width'), get OrigWidth() {return this.origWidth;},
                           origLeft: 'auto', get OrigLeft() {return this.origLeft;},
                           origRight: $('#photography-tab').css('right'), get OrigRight() {return this.origRight;},
                           expandedWidth: '40%', get ExpandedWidth() {return this.expandedWidth;},
                           expandedLeft: 'auto', get ExpandedLeft() {return this.expandedLeft;},
                           expandedRight: $('#photography-tab').css('right'), get ExpandedRight() {return this.expandedRight;}};

var gamesSection = {id: '#games-tab', get ID() {return this.id;},
                          selector: '#gamepad-icon', get Selector() {return this.selector;},
                          origWidth: $('#games-tab').css('width'), get OrigWidth() {return this.origWidth;},
                          origLeft: $('#games-tab').css('left'), get OrigLeft() {return this.origLeft;},
                          expandedWidth: '40%', get ExpandedWidth() {return this.expandedWidth;}};
```

**Handlers**

```js
    // Handles aboutme section functionality
    function handleAboutMeSection(elemToAnimate, selectedElem, active, animateDuration=500, fadeInDuration=500, fadeOutDuration=250){
        // First click
        if (active){
            // Animate vertically first
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({height: elemToAnimate.ExpandedHeight,
                                     top: elemToAnimate.ExpandedTop,
                                     bottom: elemToAnimate.OrigBottom}, animateDuration);
            // Animate horizontally second
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({width: elemToAnimate.ExpandedWidth,
                                 left: elemToAnimate.ExpandedLeft,
                                 right: elemToAnimate.ExpandedRight}, animateDuration)


            // Fade in content and remove active class
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).find(".content").fadeIn(fadeInDuration);
            $(selectedElem).removeClass('active');
        // Second click
        } else {
            // Fade out content
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).find(".content").fadeOut(fadeOutDuration, function(){
                // Animate horizontally first
                $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({width: elemToAnimate.OrigWidth,
                                         left: elemToAnimate.OrigLeft,
                                         right: elemToAnimate.OrigRight}, animateDuration);
                // Animate vertically second
                $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({height: elemToAnimate.OrigHeight,
                                          top: elemToAnimate.OrigTop,
                                          bottom: elemToAnimate.OrigBottom}, animateDuration)
            });
            // Add active class back in
            $(selectedElem).addClass('active');
        }
    }

    //Handles photography tab functionality
    function handleTabs(elemToAnimate, selectedElem, active, animateDuration=500, fadeInDuration=500, fadeOutDuration=250){
        // First click
        if (active){
            // Only animate horizontally
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({width: elemToAnimate.ExpandedWidth,
                                  left: elemToAnimate.ExpandedLeft,
                                  right: elemToAnimate.ExpandedRight}, animateDuration)

            // Fade in content and remove active class
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).find(".content").fadeIn(fadeInDuration);
            $(selectedElem).removeClass('active');
        // Second click
        } else {
            // Fade out content and only animate horizontally
            $(elemToAnimate.ID).find(".content").fadeOut(fadeOutDuration, function(){
                $(elemToAnimate.ID).animate({width: elemToAnimate.OrigWidth,
                                         left: elemToAnimate.OrigLeft,
                                         right: elemToAnimate.OrigRight}, animateDuration);
            });
            // Add active class back in
            $(selectedElem).addClass('active');
        }
    }
```

**Main**

```js
    //Hide content initially
    $(".content").hide();
    //Handle click events
    $(".image").click(function() {
        //On first click
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            switch($(this).attr('id')) {
                case 'person-icon':
                handleAboutMeSection(aboutmeSection, aboutmeSection.Selector, true);
                break;

                case 'gamepad-icon':
                handleTabs(gamesSection, gamesSection.Selector, true);
                break;

                case 'camera-icon':
                handleTabs(photographySection, photographySection.Selector, true);
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        // On second click
        } else {
            switch($(this).attr('id')) {
                case 'person-icon':
                handleAboutMeSection(aboutmeSection, aboutmeSection.Selector, false);
                break;

                case 'gamepad-icon':
                handleTabs(gamesSection, gamesSection.Selector, false);
                break;

                case 'camera-icon':
                handleTabs(photographySection, photographySection.Selector, false);
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like a question that belongs over on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. It has a TL:DR feel to it.

However I think I know what you are going through so let me address your questions and just glimpse over the code:

1) **What should I consider programmatically when taking the scalability of an app into account? How can this code be cleaned up/refined?**

This depends on what you plan to do with it. Do you need to implement more blocks, maybe use tabs and blocks together to have several different options ? More important than that, do you wish to come back a few years later and don't slap yourself in the forehead, then yes, you probably could refactor this a bit.

Before I start, take this with a grain of salt. Every programmer is different, so my refactor examples may not tingle with others. If the code works, it is #right#. Only the code with errors is #wrong#. Again, another opinion of mine.

So, what I would do is create a settings literal object to deal with the section part, that contained what you needed. Lets take about me for example. Here's how I would do just the js code:

```
// Definitions ----------------------------------------
var section =  {
    elem: null,
    selector: null,
    content: null,
    opened: false,
    origDim: { },
    currDim: { },
    expdDim: { },
    setup: function(settings) { // gets the settings and sets up the initial position
        var self = this;
        if (    !(
                self.is_set(settings) ||
                self.is_set(settings.elem) ||
                self.is_set(settings.selector) ||
                self.is_set(settings.content)
            )
        )
        {
            console.log('Your settings must send out an element, a content and a selector');
        } else {
            self.elem = settings.elem;
            self.selector = settings.selector;
            self.content = settings.content;
            self.origDim = self.getPosition();
        }
        return self; // this allows chaining
    },
    // Sets up the range of motion the section will have
    setRange: function(expdDim) {
        var self = this;
        if ( !(self.is_set(expdDim)) ) {
            console.log('You have to provide a set of new positions.')
        } else {
            self.expdDim = {
                width: (self.is_set(expdDim.width)?expdDim.width:self.currDim.width),
                height: (self.is_set(expdDim.height)?expdDim.height:self.currDim.height),
                top: (self.is_set(expdDim.top)?expdDim.top:self.currDim.top),
                right: (self.is_set(expdDim.right)?expdDim.right:self.currDim.right),
                bottom: (self.is_set(expdDim.bottom)?expdDim.bottom:self.currDim.bottom),
                left: (self.is_set(expdDim.left)?expdDim.left:self.currDim.left)
            };
        }
        return self; // this allows chaining
    },
    // Toggles from opened to close by listening to a property opened
    toggle: function(animTime, fadeInTime, fadeOutTime) {
        var self = this;
        if (self.opened) self.close(animTime, fadeOutTime);
        else self.open(self.expdDim, animTime, fadeInTime);
        return self; // this allows chaining
    },
    // Expands the section
    open: function(newDim, animTime, fadeInTime) {
        var self = this;
        if (    !(self.is_set(newDim)) )    console.log('You must send new dimensions!');
        else {
            var elem = $(self.elem);
            elem
                .animate(self.optionsVert(newDim), animTime)
                .animate(self.optionsHorz(newDim), animTime)
                .promise().done( function() {
                  $(this).find(self.content).fadeIn(fadeInTime)
                    self.currDim = self.getPosition();
                    self.opened = true;
                    });
        }
        return self; // this allows chaining
    },
    // Closes the section
    close: function(animTime, fadeOutTime) {
        var self = this;
        var elem = $(self.elem);
        // first fade
        elem.find(self.content)
            .fadeOut(fadeOutTime)
            .promise()
            .done(function(){
                elem
                    .animate(self.optionsHorz(self.origDim), animTime)
                    .animate(self.optionsVert(self.origDim), animTime)
                    .promise()
                    .done( function() {
                        self.currDim = self.getPosition();
                        self.opened = false;
                    });
            });
        return self; // this allows chaining
    },
    // HELPER FUNCTIONS - these do not allow chaining - used as private functions
    // Sets up original dimensions based on the element 
    getPosition: function() {
        var self = this;
        var offset = $(self.elem).offset();
        var posDim = {
            width: $(self.elem).width()+'px',
            height: $(self.elem).height()+'px',
            top: offset.top+'px',
            right: parseInt(offset.left)+parseInt($(self.elem).width())+'px',
            bottom: parseInt(offset.top)+parseInt($(self.elem).height())+'px',
            left: offset.left+'px'
        };
        return posDim;
    },
    // validates if a given variable is set
    is_set: function(vary) {
        return (typeof vary != 'undefined');
    },
    // returns a subset of dimension variables belonging to the X plane
    optionsHorz: function(newDim) {
        return {
            width: newDim.width,
            left: newDim.left,
            right: newDim.right
        };
    },
    // returns a subset of dimension variables belonging to the Y plane
    optionsVert: function(newDim) {
        return {
            height: newDim.height,
            top: newDim.top,
            bottom: newDim.bottom
        };
    }
};

// Definitions ----------------------------------------

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Setting up section about me
    var aboutme = section;
    aboutme.setup({
        elem: '#aboutme-section',
        selector: '#person-icon',
        content: '.content'
    }).setRange({
        width: '65%',
        height: '450px',
        top: '65%'
    });

    //Hide content initially
    $(".content").hide();
    //Handle click events
    $(".image").click(function() {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
            case 'person-icon':
                aboutme.toggle(500,500,250);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    });

});
```

This is how you can templatize your sections. You can augment this block to augment it's functionality but, if you take a look, the settings get pretty thin and simple.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond to this to such a great answer. Really surprised you went out of your way to write all of this up. This is absolutely the kind of general solution I was trying to achieve. While I did end up changing the design of the site (new design here: www.domsilva.com) I will be storing this code away as I will surely need it later on. Thanks again for the help.